# call separated asynctask class from framgent

Tags: android, mysql, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a fragment which contain a recycler view, i call the asynctask to load files from mysql to the recyclerview, i tried it first on activity it work no problem, but when I replace it by fragment, it doesn't work here's my files:

**BackgroundTask.class**

```
  package com.example.harry.recylcerviewdyn;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Created by FairDz on 19/04/2017.
 */
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Promotion,Void>
{
    Context ctx;
    Activity activity;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<Promotion> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    public BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        activity = (Activity) ctx;
    }
    String json_string ="http://10.0.2.2/promotion_info/get_promotion_details.php";
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
       recyclerView = (RecyclerView)activity.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ctx);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList,ctx);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_string);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line ;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
            }
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            String json_string = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
            int count = 0;
            while (count<jsonArray.length())
            {
                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                count++;
                Promotion promotion = new Promotion(JO.getInt("id"),JO.getString("nom_supermarche"),JO.getString("logo_supermarche"),JO.getString("nom_produit"),JO.getString("logo_produit"),JO.getDouble("prix"),JO.getDouble("promotion_prix"),JO.getString("description"));
                publishProgress(promotion);
            }
            Log.d("JSON STRING",json_string);
        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null ;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Promotion... values) {
        arrayList.add(values[0]);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**Fragment.class**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);

        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(getActivity());
        backgroundTask.execute();
        return view;
    }
```

I search the problem on website and I found some solution which it not work on my project like implement the asynctask directily in the framgen class

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: show error log.

Comment: The Recyclerview is in your Activity or Fragment?? Share logcat logs with error

Comment: it said "App is stopped"

Comment: @hocinebouhlala please share logcat

Comment: Event log: 06/05/2017
16:29 Gradle sync started

16:29 Gradle sync completed

16:29 Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

16:29 Gradle build finished in 21s 512ms

16:30 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

16:30 Gradle build finished in 9s 246ms

Comment: Error monitor: 05-06 16:37:58.605 4357-4643/? E/WifiConfigStore: updateConfiguration freq=2417 BSSID=c0:4a:00:a7:02:b6 RSSI=-70 "TP-LINK_A702B6"WPA_PSK
05-06 16:38:00.113 5279-5381/? E/HwLauncher: SettingsEx , no such field.
05-06 16:38:00.730 3745-3745/? E/Thermal-daemon: [ap] temp_new :34  temp_old :35
05-06 16:38:00.731 3745-3745/? E/Thermal-daemon: Report temperature: [ap] temp :34  report_threshold:1
05-06 16:38:01.632 4357-4643/? E/WifiConfigStore: updateConfiguration freq=2417 BSSID=c0:4a:00:a7:02:b6 RSSI=-70 "TP-LINK_A702B6"WPA_PSK

Answer (score 1):

**When Activity**

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView)activity.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
```

**When Fragment**

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView)ctx.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
```

**Good Approach**

**Remove** this line  `activity = (Activity) ctx;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to call *AsyncTask* in **onActivityCreated**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   new AsyncTask().execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
backgroundTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

instead

```
 backgroundTask.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not mess it like that - AsyncTask is responsible for executing tasks in background, don't include any UI widget dependencies into that - it will cause memory leaks when operation takes too long and Activity is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use recycler view in post execute. Try to send ArrayList return to activity using callback interface and implement that interface in activity or fragment that does not affect your view and also set adapter in create view and after callback only use 
 `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.
 list will be refresed and new data will populate.